# Parse a file in various parts

Tags: list, file, parsing, python-2.7

I am trying to parse a file that contains the following

```
# This is 1st line
# This is 2nd line
ATOM This is 3rd line 

ATOM This is 4th line
# This is 5th line
# This is 6th line
```

I wish to use Python 2.7 to parse the file and append lines up to the line starting with `ATOM` to a list `head_list`, the lines starting with `ATOM` to `atom_list` and lines after the line containing `ATOM` to a `tail_list`.

I want to use the `startswith()` in Python to match lines that start with `ATOM`. Below is my code, i am passing counter variable which has the index of the last line in the file which starts with ATOM. yet my output does not seem to be right

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os
global counter
def AskForFileName () :
        file_name = raw_input('Enter the name of the input file \n')
        try:
          if not file_name :
            print "You did not enter a name !"
        except :
          exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
          fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
          print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)

        return file_name

def ReadFileContents (file_name) :
          #print file_name
          file = open(file_name,'r')
          file_strings=file.readlines()
          return file_strings

def BuildHeadList(all_file_contents) :
        head_list=[]
        i=0
        try :
          for line in all_file_contents:
            if line.startswith("ATOM") :
               break
            else :
              i=int(i)+1
              #print "BuildHeadList :"+str(i)+"\n"
              head_list.append(line)
        except : 
          exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
          fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
          print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)

        return head_list

def BuildAtomList(all_file_contents) :
          atom_list=[]
          i=0
          global counter
          try :
             for i,line in enumerate(all_file_contents):
              if line.startswith("ATOM") :
                 atom_list.append(line)
                 counter=i
                 #i=int(i)+1
                 #print "BuildAtomList :"+str(i)+"\n"
              else :

                 continue
          except :
              exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
              fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
              print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
          return atom_list

def BuildTailList(all_file_contents) :
          tail_list=[]
          i=0
          global counter
          counter=counter+1
          print "Counter value is "+str(counter)
          try :
             for i,line in enumerate(all_file_contents,counter):
                   print i
                   tail_list.append(line)
          except :
              exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
              fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
              print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
          return tail_list

def WriteNewFile(head_list,atom_list,tail_list):
           file=open('output.txt',  'w')
           #for line in head_list :
            #     print>>file, line,

           #for line in atom_list :
            #     print>>file, line,      

           for line in tail_list :
                 print>>file, line,

           file.close()
file_name=AskForFileName()
all_file_contents=ReadFileContents(file_name)
head_list=BuildHeadList(all_file_contents)
atom_list=BuildAtomList(all_file_contents)
tail_list=BuildTailList(all_file_contents )
WriteNewFile(head_list,atom_list,tail_list)
```

Comment: *"Could you provide me some tips..."* is **not** an on-topic question here. Write some code!

Comment: quick and dirty pseudocode to give you one possible solution: line = nextLine(); while !line.startswith(ATOM) head_list.push(line); line = nextLine(); while line.startswith(ATOM) atom_list.push(line); line = nextLine(); while line tail_list.push(line); line = nextLine();

Comment: When writing the output to the file, i found that the tail_list seems to have lines above the lines that start with ATOM. when i print the value of counter it has the correct value, but the tail_list seems to have all the lines. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
enumerate(all_file_contents, counter)
```

Doesn't do what you think it does; it iterates over everything in the lists, but numbers them starting from `counter` instead of `0`. A minimal fix would be:

```
for i, line in enumerate(all_file_contents):
     if i >= counter:
         tail_list.append(line)
```

However, much better would be to not iterate over the whole file three times. In particular, note that `tail_list = all_file_contents[counter:]` gets the result you want. Additionally, get rid of the `global` and pass `counter` around explicitly.

You should also read [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).